# BlackBerry options screen in application

Tags: blackberry, preferences

I would like to create an "Options" screen in a blackberry application, so when running the application they click the blackberry button and have an "Options" MenuItem. I can create this manually, but I wonder if there's a standard way to do it, as I noticed all of the standard applications (contacts, calendar, messaging, etc) all have a standard look and feel.

Please note I am not talking about the OptionsManager/OptionsProvider - these are to provide options for the application in the global settings, not within the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, there is no standard option screen in BlackBerry. Take a look on [Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276). There is FieldSet component inside their sample project, it allows to create layouting and styling very similar to standard option screens.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the [CHANGE_OPTION](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html#CHANGE_OPTION) MenuItem?

You can use [MenuItem.getPrefab(int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html#getPrefab%28int%29) with [MenuItem.CHANGE_OPTION](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/MenuItem.html#CHANGE_OPTION).

Comment: interesting. i might have. i didn't know this existed. what does it do when it run() ?

Comment: Can't remember; and not in a place to test. Will let you know later :)